# Laravel 5.2 Javascript call with blade parameter

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I have (currently) the following bit of code in my module.blade.php:

```
@section('scripts')
  <script type="text/javascript">
      createMixin(['{{ $module }}']);
  </script>
@endsection
```

**Explanation**:

- $module is a variable holding a JSON packed with simple key => value, but also with key => object. It is loaded previously in a Controller and displayed in the blade.php.

Example:

{
     "title":"Title",
     "name":"dummy",
     "file":"dummy",
     "layout":"normal",
     "fields": [
       {
         "name": "bla"
       }
      ]
    }

- Function createMixin() would ideally generate a HTML out of Jade with the options inside $module (already existing).

**Problem** is: This does end in an error message: "htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

**Done so far:** I have already tried several things:

```
@section('scripts')
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var fields = $.parseJSON("{!! $module !!}");
      createMixin(fields);
  </script>
@endsection
```

And:

```
@section('scripts')
  <script type="text/javascript">
      createMixin("{!! JSON.parse($module) !!}");
  </script>
@endsection
```

And:

```
@section('scripts')
  <script type="text/javascript">
      createMixin("{!! json_encode($module) !!}");
  </script>
@endsection
```

And:

```
@section('scripts')
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(this).createMixin("{{ $module }}");
  </script>
@endsection
```

I have had a look at several posts here (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595446/laravel-javascript-passing-an-array-from-backend-to-a-array-in-javascript)) and in other sources, they tell the people to use the php implode method or just a simple usage of "{!! !!}". But this all ends up in the same error message.

**Question**: What am I overlooking here? What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit:

As requested my Javascript function:

```
//generate one jade mixin
function createMixin(module) {
    //first load JSON...
    var json = $.parseJSON(loadJSON(module["file"]));
    //get options for mixin
    var options = json.fields;
    //detect jade file
    var jadepath = RESOURCES_DIR + "views/jade/" + json.file + "/template.jade";

    //check if file exists
    $.ajax({
        'url': jadepath,
        'type': 'HEAD',
        'error': function() {},
        'success': function () {
            var html = renderJade(options, jadepath);
            //save html into json
            json.html = html;
            var tmp = new Blob([html], { type: 'plain/text;charset=utf-8' });

        }
    });
};
```

Comment: can you tell, what this method `createMixin()` do ? and can you show us PHP receiving end ? because the message `"htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"` is based on PHP end.

Comment: @Qazi Added the Javascript above. I call this function and plan to change an elements content with the generated html. I commented out most of it though for this test; I only had the first line of code, the rest was commented out for this.

Comment: Are you getting the same error for each of the other examples you posted? It looks like the first one should work. Maybe double check what's in `$module`? You should be able to simply put: `var fields = {!! $module !!}`

Comment: @Tama no, it sadly does not work... I have absolutely no idea why. Even if I just do a console.log in the Javascript file without any other stuff I have written it won't accept the variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I found the solution.

I had to first do the parameter initialisation in PHP:

```
<?php $json = json_encode($module); ?>
```

And then separately call the Javascript function via:

```
@section('scripts')
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          var module = {!! $json !!};
          createMixin(module);
      });
  </script>
@endsection
```

So in total it would look like this:

```
<?php $json = json_encode($module); ?>

@section('scripts')
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          var module = {!! $json !!};
          createMixin(module);
      });
  </script>
@endsection
```